# Splitting the Hopf map in two

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, hopf-fibration

Given the Hopf map $h:S^3\to S^2$ and an inclusion $i:S^2\hookrightarrow S^3$, the map $h\circ i:S^2\to S^2$ has mapping degree zero. Therefore, it is homotopic to the constant map and the image of the equator $S^2\subset S^3$ can be contracted to a point. This gives a representative of the sum $[f]+[g]\in\pi_3(S^2)$ for some $[f],[g]\in\pi_3(S^2)$. Since the Hopf map represents the class $[h]=1\in\mathbb{Z}=\pi_3(S^2)$, this would imply that $[f]+[g]=1$, i.e. that the Hopf invariants of $f$ and $g$ sum to $1$. However, it seems awkward that the contraction of the equator of such a canonical map as the Hopf map would yield two maps with Hopf invariant not having the same absolute value. Or is this in fact the case?

Comment: What is $g$? Also, what do you mean by "This gives a representative of the sum..."?

Comment: Note that there is nothing special about the Hopf map here. Any map $h: S^3\to S^2$ is null-homotopic when restricted to the equator, since the inclusion $S^2\hookrightarrow S^3$ is null-homotopic. So there will be a map $h':S^3\vee S^3\to S^2$ which expresses $h$ as a sum. In general, though, $h'$ will depend on the null-homotopy. Choosing either of the standard null-homotopies will no doubt result in one of $f$ or $g$ being null and the other being $h$.

Comment: So it really does seem to be the case. Thanks for the answer, Mark! (You can post it as such if you want)

Comment: Do you mean $h \circ i$ in the first sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an expanded version of my comment above.

Let $h: S^3\to S^2$ be the Hopf map (or any other pointed map for that matter). Choose a pointed null-homotopy $i_t: S^2\to S^3$ of the standard inclusion $i:S^2\hookrightarrow S^3$.

The composition $h\circ i_t$ is a null-homotopy of $h\circ i$, and therefore gives a map $$h': S^3\cup_i C(S^2) \to S^2$$ defined on the mapping cone of $i$ which extends $h$. We can identify $h'$ up to homotopy with a map $h'=(f\vee g): S^3\vee S^3\to S^2$ satisfying $h'\circ \nu\simeq h$, where $\nu:S^3\to S^3\vee S^3$ denotes the pinch map.

Thus $[h]=[f]+[g]\in \pi_3(S^2)$, as you say, but it is easy to see that $[f]$ and $[g]$ are going to depend on $i_t$. I'll leave the details of what goes where as an exercise, but it seems to me that a standard $i_t$ would result in one or other of $[f]$ and $[g]$ being $0$ and the other being $[h]$.